# Calculate Number of Instructions in Assembly File

Tags: assembly

I have a SPARC Assembly file which is run on the SPARC T1 RTL code (via teh assembler converting it to memory image). But I need to know how many instructions are being executed by the RTL. It is not possible to count number of instructions manually in a file. I would very much appreciate if you could show my a way to do this...

Since the file is large, I am attaching the dropbox link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48635184/exu_muldiv.s

But here is first few lines of the code:

```
    /***********************************************************************
 * Name:    exu_muldiv.s
 * Date:    April 23, 2003
 *
 *  Description: Execute Mulx, Mulscc, Smul, Smulcc, Umul, Umulcc,
 *  Sdiv, Sdivcc, Sdivx, Udiv, Udivcc, Udivx with interesting data 
 *  patterns in multiple threads. Also play with delay slots and
 *  intermixed mul and div operations.
 *
 *  This test depends on SAS for result checking.    
 *
 **********************************************************************/

! be sure to update when adding cases...
#define NUM_MUL_CASES 6
#define NUM_DIV_CASES 4
#define NUM_IMMED_CASES 5    

! for divide by zero cases
#define H_T0_Division_By_Zero
#define My_T0_Division_By_Zero \
rdpr    %tstate, %i1; \
rdpr    %tt, %i1; \
rdpr    %tpc, %i0; \
rdpr    %tnpc, %i1; \
done; \
nop;    

/*******************************************************/    
#include "boot.s"

.global main
main:
th_fork(th_main,%l0)        ! start up to four threads.
    ! All threads do the same thing, but with different data patterns. 
    ! No need to run more than one core.
th_main_0:
    setx    mul_data_t0,%g7,%g1
        ba  all_threads1
    nop

th_main_1:
        setx    mul_data_t1,%g7,%g1
    ba  all_threads1
    nop

th_main_2:
    setx    mul_data_t2,%g7,%g1
        ba  all_threads1
    nop

th_main_3:
    setx    mul_data_t3,%g7,%g1
    ba  all_threads1
    nop

all_threads1:       
    !*************************************************************
    ! Operand2 as a register:    MULX, UMUL, SMUL, UMULcc, SMULcc
    !*************************************************************
    add %g0,NUM_MUL_CASES,%g2
    mova    %icc,%g1,%g3        ! keep the multiply operand address handy

mul_loop1:
    ldx [%g1],%l1
    ldx [%g1+8],%l2
    wr  %g0,%g0,%ccr        ! ccr clear

    mulx    %l1,%l2,%l4
    umul    %l1,%l2,%l5
    rd  %y,%i1          ! be sure SAS looks at Y-reg
    smul    %l1,%l2,%l6
    rd  %y,%i1

        wr  %g0,%g0,%ccr        ! clear ccr     
    umulcc  %l1,%l2,%l7     
    rd  %y,%i1
        wr  %g0,%g0,%ccr        
    smulcc  %l1,%l2,%l6     
    rd  %y,%i1

        wr  %g0,0xff,%ccr       ! set ccr. Should not matter.       
    umulcc  %l1,%l2,%l7     
    rd  %y,%i1
        wr  %g0,0xff,%ccr       
    smulcc  %l1,%l2,%l6     
    rd  %y,%i1    

    sub %g2,0x1,%g2
    brnz,pt %g2,mul_loop1
    add %g1,0x10,%g1        ! move operand pointer

    !**********************************
    ! Operand2 as a register:    MULScc
    !**********************************
#ifndef MULSCC_BUGS    
        mova    %icc,%g3,%g1        ! same ops as mul_loop1
    add %g0,NUM_MUL_CASES,%g2       
mulscc_1:
    wr  %g0,%g0,%ccr        ! ccr clear    
    ldx [%g1],%l1
    ldx [%g1+8],%l2
    wr  %l1,0,%y        ! lower bits of multiplier into Y-reg
    rd  %y,%l0          ! for sas debug
    srl %l1,0,%l1       ! clear rs1 upper
    srl %l2,0,%l2       ! clear rs2 upper
    mulx    %l1,%l2,%l4     ! save for later compare
    add %g0,0,%l1       ! clear rs1 (product upper) completely

    add %g0,32,%l3      ! bit position counter
mulscc_2:   
    sub %l3,1,%l3
    mulscc  %l1,%l2,%l1
    brgez,pt %l3,mulscc_2  
    nop 

    sllx    %l1,33,%l1      ! product upper
    rd  %y,%l3          ! product lower
    or  %l1,%l3,%l3     ! full product should be equal to mulx
    subcc   %l3,%l4,%l5
    tnz T_BAD_TRAP
    nop

    sub %g2,0x1,%g2
    brnz,pt %g2,mulscc_1
    add %g1,0x10,%g1        ! move operand pointer
#endif    

    !****************************************
    ! Operand2 as a register:    SDIVX, UDIVX
    !****************************************
    rdth_id             ! get thid in %o1
    cmp %o1,0
    be  th_divx_0
    cmp %o1,1
    be  th_divx_1
    cmp %o1,2
    be  th_divx_2
    nop
    ba  th_divx_3       ! if there are more than 4 threads...
    nop

th_divx_0:
    setx    divx_data_t0,%g7,%g1
        ba  all_threads2
    nop

th_divx_1:
    setx    divx_data_t1,%g7,%g1
        ba  all_threads2
    nop

th_divx_2:
    setx    divx_data_t2,%g7,%g1
        ba  all_threads2
    nop

th_divx_3:
    setx    divx_data_t3,%g7,%g1  
    ba  all_threads2
    nop

all_threads2:       
    add %g0,NUM_DIV_CASES,%g2

divx_loop1:
    ldx [%g1],%l1
    ldx [%g1+8],%l2
    wr  %g0,%g0,%ccr        ! ccr clear 

    sdivx   %l1,%l2,%l3
    udivx   %l1,%l2,%l4
    sdivx   %l2,%l1,%l5     ! use each operand as divisor and dividend
    udivx   %l2,%l1,%l6

    sub %g2,0x1,%g2
    brnz,pt %g2,divx_loop1
    add %g1,0x10,%g1        ! move operand pointer
```

Comment: I wonder if you could run it in some emulator and if you could hack the emulator to give you the number of instructions run (forgive me if this is non sense)

Comment: So you need the dynamic instruction count (total instructions executed), not the static insn count (total insn in the file; insns inside loops still only count once.  i.e. code-size)?

Comment: @Leo, you are right, I am running it on VCS Simulator, but I just don't know how/where to do it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, static instruction would give me a good idea of the size of the program, but what is an efficient way to count total number of instruction (static) and then I could simply multiply this with the number of loops to get the total instruction in the file that needs to be executed.

Comment: Some of your instructions are outside loops, so this would only be a rough approximation, and only works if you know the iteration count for each loop.  In any case, IDK how.  Maybe assemble it, and count bytes, since SPARC is a RISC machine with fixed-size instructions.  Or assemble->disassemble and count lines (this removes source line count from comments and labels).

Comment: What usage of doing this are you trying to address?

Comment: @FrankC., I am trying to run different workload and see the performance of the simulator (VCS in this case), I have the Cycle count from VCS but having # of Instructions would give me IPC

Comment: With that in mind I agree with Peter's answer below (+1). An instrumented observation with some category by "work/request" type would be most informative.

Answer (score 1):

I think in general the only way to know the dynamic instruction count is to actually run the code in an instrumented environment that counts instructions.  (e.g. a simulator or a CPU with perf counters).

I think a program that could reliably compute the number of instructions another program will run would be equivalent to solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

In many practical cases, branching after a loop won't depend on the result computed by the loop.  If the loop end condition is simple, like incrementing a counter up to a limit, it would be possible to just just add iterations * instructions-per-iter to a total and move on.

This is *not* a simple problem; the complexity is probably similar to writing an optimizing compiler that takes asm as its input.  You need to analyse data flow to figure stuff out about which branches will be taken, and for some code you will just have to simulate what happens.

Your best bet is almost certainly to just find a simulator / emulator like @Leo says.